# Complex stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join, sql-server-2012, subquery

I am a novice with regards to sql and I'm trying to create a rather complex stored procedure that is to be used by a report created using sql reporting services within Business Intelligence of Visual Studio.

I have a main 'Project' table that is linked various other tables by making use of link tables (the ones of interest in my stored procedure being 'Status', 'Facility' and 'Branch'). What the application does is a researcher submits a project and it goes through the following approval process:

> Specialised Health Manager > Branch Head > Health Management Team

To facilitate this approval process, another team member developed a custom Workflow solution that makes use of 'WorkflowHistory' table. What gets put in this table (among others) is the ProjectId, the WorkflowStep and the Date the workflow step was performed and a comment issued by the person who performed the step. What I want in my report is the following:

The info I want in my report is the following:

[image: Mars report fields]

The 'ProjectId' and 'Title' come from the 'Project' table. The 'Facilities', 'Branch' and 'Status' com from the tables linked to 'Project'. 'Recieved' needs to be the date the initial workflow step was performed for the project. The 'Concluded' needs to be the date the final workflow step was performed for the project. The 'Comment' needs to be the comment that was left for the final workflow step.

So, the data for each line in the report is to come from the following places:

- one line from 'Project'
- one line from 'Branch'
- one line from 'Status'
- multiple lines from 'Facility' (below on my running attempt I'm only returning the first facility from the sub-query, but I want all facilities assigned to the project, comma-space delimited)
- two different lines from 'WorkflowHistory'

The user passes the following parameters to filter the report:

- From Date - to get all reports received after a specific date (this will be the 'ActionedOn' for the first workflow step in 'WorkflowHistory')
- To Date - to get all reports received before a specific date (this will be the 'ActionedOn' for the final workflow step in 'WorkflowHistory')
- Status - Filter projects with a specific status
- Branch - Filter projects assigned to a specific branch

[image: Mars Report parameters]

I have tried to accomplish all of this with the below stored procedure. This is my running attempt, that I'm continually working on. The issues I'm still having include the following:

- The date range filtering doesn't work
- The I can only return the first facility in the sub-query
  (following is the issues still existing when commenting out the entire WHERE portion)
- The final workflow step of the project might be anything between 2 and 5, depending on whether it was approved and when it was rejected. I need to figure out how to get the 'Concluded' date as well as the Comment left on this step.
- I pass the 'Status' in a parameter. I need to figure out how to filer by one status or by all (which is not actually all the statuses, but the final 3 being 'Approved', 'Declined' and 'Concluded'). Same for branch.

Edit: It is now what, 5 hours later and I've updated the stored procedure below. I've sorted most of the issues out by making use of a temporary table variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_CityHealthResearchRequestsReport]
@FromDate DATETIME,
@ToDate DATETIME,
@StatusId int,
@BranchId int,
@Count INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    ProjectId INT,
    Recieved DATETIME,
    Concluded DATETIME,
    Comment VARCHAR(8000)
)

IF @StatusId <> 0 AND @BranchId <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TempTable (ProjectId, Recieved, Concluded, Comment)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 1
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Recieved,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Concluded,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.Comment
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Comment
    FROM
        Project p
        JOIN WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        JOIN ProjectBranch pb ON pb.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    WHERE
        p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = @StatusId
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)

    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        p.Title,
        STUFF (
               (SELECT ', ' + f.Name
                FROM dbo.Facility f
                LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectFacility pf ON f.FacilityId = pf.FacilityId
                WHERE pf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '') AS Facilities,
        tt.Recieved,
        tt.Concluded,
        b.BranchName,
        st.Description AS StatusText,
        tt.Comment,
        tt.Concluded - tt.Recieved AS Turnaround
    FROM
        dbo.Project p
        INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON p.ProjectId = tt.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectBranch pb ON p.ProjectId = pb.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch b ON pb.BranchId = b.BranchId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
    WHERE
        p.StatusId = @StatusId
        AND b.BranchId = @BranchId
    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END

IF @StatusId <> 0 AND @BranchId = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TempTable (ProjectId, Recieved, Concluded, Comment)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 1
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Recieved,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Concluded,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.Comment
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Comment
    FROM
        Project p
        JOIN WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        JOIN ProjectBranch pb ON pb.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    WHERE
        p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = @StatusId
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)

    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        p.Title,
        STUFF (
               (SELECT ', ' + f.Name
                FROM dbo.Facility f
                LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectFacility pf ON f.FacilityId = pf.FacilityId
                WHERE pf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '') AS Facilities,
        tt.Recieved,
        tt.Concluded,
        b.BranchName,
        st.Description AS StatusText,
        tt.Comment,
        tt.Concluded - tt.Recieved AS Turnaround
    FROM
        dbo.Project p
        INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON p.ProjectId = tt.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectBranch pb ON p.ProjectId = pb.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch b ON pb.BranchId = b.BranchId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
    WHERE
        p.StatusId = @StatusId
    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END

IF @StatusId = 0 AND @BranchId <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TempTable (ProjectId, Recieved, Concluded, Comment)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 1
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Recieved,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Concluded,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.Comment
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Comment
    FROM
        Project p
        JOIN WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        JOIN ProjectBranch pb ON pb.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    WHERE
        p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 5
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
        OR p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 6
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
        OR p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 7
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)

    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        p.Title,
        STUFF (
               (SELECT ', ' + f.Name
                FROM dbo.Facility f
                LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectFacility pf ON f.FacilityId = pf.FacilityId
                WHERE pf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '') AS Facilities,
        tt.Recieved,
        tt.Concluded,
        b.BranchName,
        st.Description AS StatusText,
        tt.Comment,
        tt.Concluded - tt.Recieved AS Turnaround
    FROM
        dbo.Project p
        INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON p.ProjectId = tt.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectBranch pb ON p.ProjectId = pb.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch b ON pb.BranchId = b.BranchId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
    WHERE
        p.StatusId = 5
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        OR p.StatusId = 6
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
        OR p.StatusId = 7
        AND pb.BranchId = @BranchId
    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END

IF @StatusId = 0 AND @BranchId = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TempTable (ProjectId, Recieved, Concluded, Comment)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 1
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Recieved,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.ActionedOn
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Concluded,
        (SELECT TOP 1 wf.Comment
         FROM WorkflowHistory wf
         WHERE wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 4
         OR wf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
         AND wf.WorkflowStep = 5
         ORDER BY wf.WorkflowHistoryId DESC) AS Comment
    FROM
        Project p
        JOIN WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        JOIN ProjectBranch pb ON pb.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    WHERE
        p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 5
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
        OR p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 6
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
        OR p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
        AND p.StatusId = 7
        AND w.WorkflowStep = 1
        AND (w.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)

    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProjectId,
        p.Title,
        STUFF (
               (SELECT ', ' + f.Name
                FROM dbo.Facility f
                LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectFacility pf ON f.FacilityId = pf.FacilityId
                WHERE pf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '') AS Facilities,
        tt.Recieved,
        tt.Concluded,
        b.BranchName,
        st.Description AS StatusText,
        tt.Comment,
        tt.Concluded - tt.Recieved AS Turnaround
    FROM
        dbo.Project p
        INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON p.ProjectId = tt.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectBranch pb ON p.ProjectId = pb.ProjectId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch b ON pb.BranchId = b.BranchId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
    WHERE
        p.StatusId = 5
        OR p.StatusId = 6
        OR p.StatusId = 7
    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things wrong with your code:

- You are repeating the same code over and over again. Instead branching by @StatusId and @BranchId you can handled it in the `WHERE` clause.
- You are using @StatusId = 0 and @BranchId = 0 for missing value, this should be represented by NULL.
- Where you are using scalar correlated sub-queries I'd use joins.

Enough talking, I believe this query does what you want:

```
-- find out the final step for each project
WITH FinalStep AS
(
    SELECT ProjectId, MAX(WorkflowStep) as MaxWorkflowStep
    FROM WorkflowHistory
    WHERE WorkflowStep > 1
    GROUP BY ProjectId
)
SELECT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.Title,
    -- this is ugly consider creating a scalar function to encapsulate it
    STUFF (
           (SELECT ', ' + f.Name
            FROM dbo.Facility f
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ProjectFacility pf ON f.FacilityId = pf.FacilityId
            WHERE pf.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
            FOR XML PATH (''))
            , 1, 1, '') AS Facilities,
    wf1.ActionedOn AS Recieved,
    wf2.ActionedOn AS Concluded,
    b.BranchName,
    st.Description AS StatusText,
    wf2.Comment,
    wf2.ActionedOn - w1.ActionedOn AS Turnaround
FROM
    Project p
    INNER JOIN WorkflowHistory wf1 
        ON p.ProjectId = wf1.ProjectId 
        AND wf1.WorkflowStep = 1
    LEFT JOIN FinalStep fs 
        ON fs.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    LEFT JOIN WorkflowHistory wf2 
        ON p.ProjectId = wf2.ProjectId 
        AND wf2.WorkflowStep = fs.MaxWorkflowStep
    INNER JOIN ProjectBranch pb 
        ON pb.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch b 
        ON pb.BranchId = b.BranchId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Status st 
        ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
WHERE
    p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
    -- IF @StatusId = 0 THEN p.StatusId = 5 or 6 or 7 ELSE p.StatusId = @StatusId
    AND ((@StatusId = 0 AND p.StatusId IN (5,6,7)) OR p.StatusId = @StatusId)
    -- IF @BranchId = 0 THEN no filter ELSE pb.BranchId = @BranchId
    AND (@BranchId = 0 OR pb.BranchId = @BranchId)
    AND (wf1.ActionedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
```

I have no idea why the date filter is not working, looks ok to me. I didn't inspect the facility concatenation either but you should be able to google this stuff pretty easily. I suggest you extract the code into a function. You can then test it separately and the query will look much nicer.